# Redirect some files in directory, "not found" others

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an old directory on my server which has some files that people are still trying to access. I'd like to make most of the files in this directory inaccessible (404 not found for preference), but for about six of them I'd like to re-direct browsers to copies of these files in another folder. Is this do-able with .htaccess? If so, how?

My initial approach was this:

```
public_html/.htaccess (contains Redirect 301 /Old/Fred.pdf http://example.org/Fred.pdf)
public_html/Old/.htaccess (contains order allow, deny // deny from all)
```

hoping that the Redirect in the root .htaccess would over-ride the .htaccess in directory Old, but it doesn't.

Comment: Why would you want to use DENY, which would make your server respond with a 403 Forbidden, when what you actually want is a 404?

Comment: Sheer ignorance on my part, I'm afraid. I know just enough about .htaccess to get by, and that's not saying much.

Comment: Well easiest thing to do would probably be to just go and rename the directory … then people trying to access files in it should get a 404 automatically (for those files that you did not redirect earlier).

Comment: Yes, I can see that would work, but I'd really like to retain the name of the old directory so that it can be located easily. It does contain some useful stuff, just not stuff that we want to make available on the web.

Comment: Well then I’d just put a .htaccess into that directory, containing RewriteRule for the files that should be rewritten to another location, and if none of those match, a final RewriteRule that sets a status code 404 for everything else in that directory (and possible sub-directories; if that’s not wanted, that would have to be excluded again, or the rule made more specific).

Comment: Thanks, that's given me something to work on. I appreciate your assistance.